# Probability of getting 2nd place given that we know the probability of getting first place

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I have the probability of student getting the first place in a test

```
Student A 50%
Student B 25%
Student C 20%
Student D 5%
```

Meaning that Student A has 50% chance of scoring the highest amongst all the other students.

What is the probability that Student B will get second place? If student A gets 1st place, student B is the most likely to get second place. And if Student A gets second place, Student is the most likely to get first place.

Is this problem solvable or am I missing some assumptions?

Comment: If you write for each student the probability to score $n $ points the problem will be solvable.

Comment: Can you comment a bit more on what you mean?

Comment: This means that provided information is not sufficient for answering the question.